# How to join friends cross-platform

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I bought Dungeon Defenders for PC through Steam last year when it was released.

A friend just picked it up through the Mac App Store.

Is it possible for us to play together?

We've tried both signing in through GameSpy, but the games we create never appear. We have tried to create private and public games, and we've attempted to use the "host id" filter in the top-left corner of the game list UI to find each other.

I was hoping it was a firewall issue, but the net suggests that DD works through port 80, so I think there's nothing for me to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: GameSpy is buggy and has tons of issues. Would be better if he would get it on Steam for Mac.

Comment: Not the least of which is that Gamespy's new owners have been [randomly taking down games without warning](http://games.slashdot.org/story/12/12/07/2250252/gamespys-new-owners-begin-disabling-multiplayer-without-warning).  Stay far, far away if possible.